# add XML support to JSON handling functions in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, xml, heroku

In my heroku RoR app,I have a controller in which I support JSON requests. There I have the following functions:

```
def mssg_as_json
    @message = Message.new
    @message.text = params.require(:messages)
    @message.save
    string = "http://link.com/" 
    @message.url = string + @message.id.to_s
    @message.save
    render json: { url: @message[:url] }
end

def return_mssg_as_json
  if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
    render json: { message: @message[:text] }
  else
    render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found
  end
end
```

I want to support XML requests too. My idea is to somehow convert the XML to JSON but I have no idea how. How can I modify the code to support both XML and JSON?

P.S.
My routes are:

```
get "messages/api" => "messages#return_mssg_as_json"
post "messages/api" => "messages#mssg_as_json"
```

The requests are send to main_url/messages/api

Comment: Are you using `respond_to do |format|` somewhere in your controller?

Comment: No, just specified in my routes (added them to the post)

Comment: You're going about it wrong. I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you should take advantage of the standard routes and actions. In `routes.rb`, you might do something like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :messages     
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :messages
    end
  end
end
```

Note that your controller is now nested inside `api/v1`. That allows you to identify the path as an api and to maintain versions over time. That solid's practice. Also note that you have a standard `messages` resource for your web app.

Then, your controller would look like:

```
class Api::V1::MessagesController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def create
    @message = Message.new(message_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message.save
        @message.update(url: "http://link.com/#{@message.id}")
        format.json { render json: create_hsh, status: :ok }
        format.xml  { render xml: create_hsh, staus: :ok }
      else
        format.json { render json: @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.xml  { render xml:  @message.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show 
    respond_to do |format|
      if @message = Message.find_by(id: params[:id])
        format.json { render json: show_hsh, status: :ok }
        format.xml  { render xml: show_hsh, status: :ok }
      else
        format.json { render json: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found }
        format.xml  { render xml: {errors: :not_found}, status: :not_found } 
      end
    end
  end

private

  def create_hsh
    @message.attributes.with_indifferent_access.slice(:url)
  end

  def show_hsh
    attr = @message.attributes.with_indifferent_access
    attr.slice(:foo, :bar).merge!(message: attr[:text])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:text)
  end

end
```

Note that this controller inherits from `Api::V1::BaseController`. That would be a controller that you set up to do api-relevant client authentication (key/token checking, etc.). Something, perhaps, like:

```
class Api::V1::BaseController < ActionController::API
  before_action :authorize

  def authorize
    # do your checks in a way that results in a variable @authorized?
    render(json: {errors: :unauthorized}, status: :unauthorized) unless @authorized?
  end

end
```

So, now you're using a single controller action to respond to all format types (that you elect to offer). Then, you clients would post something like:

```
http://your.api.com/messages.json
```

To get a json response. Or:

```
http://your.api.com/messages.xml
```

To get an xml response. You might notice the bit that says: `namespace :api, defaults: {format: 'json'} do`. This means that your client could call:

```
http://your.api.com/messages
```

and it will default to the `json` format.

Now you don't have a bunch of random endpoints (like `mssg_as_json`), just the regular RESTful ones that your clients will expect. Your API clients will love you for that.

You'll note that `show_hsh` is the accepted code from your earlier question.

Comment: The create and show are used for the Web part. I just want to add support for other apps to get the info.

Comment: Yes, this approach defaults to `html` as I just updated to answer. So, you can use this with the web part *and* the api part without having to write a bunch of extra actions and code. It's a very common pattern.

Comment: But I want to have a whole other url - for the wen it is just /messages while for the JSON and XML - /messages/api

Comment: As in updated answer, I would suggest `api/v1/messages` instead of `messages/api`. IMO, that's a bit more standard. And, when you get more endpoints, it will make route nesting more intuitive (again, IMO).

Comment: The XML params parser was moved to a [seperate gem](https://github.com/rails/actionpack-xml_parser) in Rails 4. But I would drop the idea  of XML support as JSON is more than sufficient. [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Preach it, @max!